# How to implement event listener in android

Tags: android, android-library

I have 2 android projects e.g. `Project A` and `Project B` .

`Project A` is a `library` project and is added as a `reference` in `Project B`.

I receive some data from a `webserver` in `Project A` . I just want to notify `Project B` that data has been received and it should start some process.

I think I will have have to implement event listener but I am unable to understand its working.

Comment: You need to use interfae. Create inerface in library project and implement in your project.

Comment: Can you give an example or any hint on how to implement it ?

Comment: post your class where you getting response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android.os.handler

Project B

```
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //update project B code
        int data=msg.arg1; //use bundle for more complex data
    }
};
```

When setting up Project A in Project B create a handler for the callback:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(callback);
```

Pass the Handler to Project A by coding a setter method that assigns the handler to one declared in Project A (e.g. Handler mHandler=null;).

```
ProjectA.setHandler(handler);
```

In Project A when you need to update B send a message through the handler:

```
Message msg=Message.obtain();
int value=10; //whatever
msg.arg1=value; //or use a Bundle
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```